# Pandas Dataframe - finding occurrences of a string in a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this (but longer):

```
    Letter  Password
0   l       klfbblslvjclmlnqklvg
1   h       pghjchdxhnjhjd
```

How do I count the number of occurences of Letter in Password? Such that it is 6 for the first row and 4 for the second row.

This does not work, because count needs a regex:

df['Occurrences'] = df['Password'].str.count(df['Letter']).astype(int)

How can I do it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case, you can use `apply`:

```
df['Occurrences'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Password'].count(x['Letter']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Letter              Password  Occurrences
0      l  klfbblslvjclmlnqklvg            6
1      h        pghjchdxhnjhjd            4
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. I will surely get more use out of the apply function in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df['Occurrences'] = [pas.count(letter) for pas, letter in zip(df['Password'], df['Letter'])]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  Letter              Password  Occurrences
0      l  klfbblslvjclmlnqklvg            6
1      h        pghjchdxhnjhjd            4
```